# Failed to build rpm from source

Tags: linux, mysql, rpm, source

I want to build a package from source, basically all I did was downloading Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.393.rhel6.src.rpm and adding `-DWITH_INNODB_MEMCACHED=ON` to spec file.

http://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/Percona-Server-5.6/Percona-Server-5.6.12-rc60.4/source/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.393.rhel6.src.rpm

```
rpmbuild -i ../Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.393.rhel6.src.rpm
rpmbuild -ba SPECS/percona-server.spec
```

but once I run rpmbuild, i get the following

```
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlcheck.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_client_test_embedded.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlhotcopy.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlimport.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlbinlog.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/mysql-test-run.pl.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_secure_installation.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/mysqldumpslow.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/myisampack.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/myisam_ftdump.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_client_test.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_zap.1
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/man/man8/mysqld.8
    -- Up-to-date: /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64/usr/share/mysql/solaris/postinstall-solaris
    + mv -v '/home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64//usr/lib64/*.a' /home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64//usr/lib64/mysql/
    mv: cannot stat `/home/jenkins/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Percona-Server-56-5.6.12-rc60.4.7.rhel6.x86_64//usr/lib64/*.a': No such file or directory
    error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.GLCsVU (%install)
RPM build errors:
Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.GLCsVU (%install)
```

/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.GLCsVU:

```
# FIXME: at some point we should stop doing this and just install everything
# FIXME: directly into /usr/lib64/mysql - perhaps at the same time as renaming
# FIXME: the shared libraries to use libmysql*-$major.$minor.so syntax
mv -v $RBR//usr/lib64/*.a $RBR//usr/lib64/mysql/

# Install logrotate and autostart
install -m 644 $MBD/release/support-files/mysql-log-rotate $RBR/etc/logrotate.d/mysql
install -m 755 $MBD/release/support-files/mysql.server $RBR/etc/init.d/mysql

# Create a symlink "rcmysql", pointing to the init.script. SuSE users
# will appreciate that, as all services usually offer this.
ln -s /etc/init.d/mysql $RBR/usr/sbin/rcmysql
```

*centos 6.4
*tried to build as non-privilege user and as root.

Comment: It does not seem to be expanding "`%{gotrevision}`", try replacing it with something. Also, I'd recommend building as a non-privileged user (http://serverfault.com/questions/10027/why-is-it-bad-to-build-rpms-as-root)

Comment: @PetterH fixed gotrevision, tried with non-privileged user and still getting this error `
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.cuSWKY (%install)
RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.cuSWKY (%install)
`

Comment: OK do you have a `$HOME/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT` folder?

Answer (score -1):

It's because your haven't set properly your rpmmacros

Can you send us either ~/rpmmacros or  ~/etc/rpmmacros  ?

Comment: cat ~/rpmmacros
cat: /root/rpmmacros: No such file or directory

Comment: My fault. it's ~/.rpmmacros

In general, have a look at this. http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:RPMMacros

It explains how to configure your rpm environment